# java Serializable interface has no function, why it affects "writeObject"/"readObject"

Tags: java, serialization, serializable

I checked that the interface of

```
Serializable
```

Has no function definition, yet when I define

```
private void readObject(ObjectOutputStream oos){
    System.out.println("readObject!!");
}
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos){
    System.out.println("writeObject!!");
}
```

function in a class, they're called while object is being serialized.

This is odd to me, if the interface defines these 2 functions, then I should override them to make sure they're called.

But in Serializable, how does compiler generate code that if I define my own "writeObject"/"readObject", they're called while serialization?

I tried to append

```
@Override
```

annotation on top of both functions, compiler reports error.

So how it works at all, would you help to give some explanations?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's essentially a dirty hack. The serialisation mechanism searches for those methods by reflection.

Comment: The compiler has no idea there is a connection between the methods and the interfaces so if you get the name/signature incorrect, it is no help.  Instead, the library looks for the method at runtime, and if it finds it, it will call them. In java 8 these methods could have been implemented using `default` however this wasn't available in Java 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.io.Serializable is a functional interface, so that means it doesn't define any methods in it. @Override annotation is put if only you really wanna make sure noone will try to modify your overridden method. The reason you got a compiler error on @Override is that there is no such method in Serializable, but instead you can find them in ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream (which use as a low-level classes FileInputStream and FileOutputStream respectively).
If you really wanna do Serialization on let's say, a list, you can do it like this:

```
package Chaper8.IO;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Serialization_Deserialization {

public static void main(String [] args){

    /*
     *  try-catch with resources, JVM makes sure to close the resources after you've finished using it
     * much easier than using finally and getting an exception for each resource closed
     * 
     */
    try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Andrei\\Desktop\\Exemple\\worker.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Andrei\\Desktop\\Exemple\\worker.txt");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);){

        //instances of the Worker class
        Worker w1 = new Worker("Worker1", 123456 , 2000.5);
        Worker w2 = new Worker("Worker2", 765436, 1500.15);
        Worker w3 = new Worker("Worker3", 364582, 1700.45);
        Worker w4 = new Worker("Worker4", 878234, 2100.34);
        ArrayList<Worker> list = new ArrayList<>();

        //just adding the persons in the list
        list.add(w1);
        list.add(w2);
        list.add(w3);
        list.add(w4);


        System.out.println("Doing serialization");
        oos.writeObject(list);

        System.out.println("Doing deserialization");
        ois.readObject();

    }catch(IOException | ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Worker.java

```
/*
 *  Worker class, basic type with variables, constructor, and toString() overridden
 *  Here I have implemented Serializable for the reason that I need to make sure that
 *  I will serialize the object within the class
 *
 *  Note that I used transient for id. transient is a special keyword which makes sure 
 * that id will not be serialized, used for security reasons.
 * 
 *  serialVersionUID is another variable which is used during deserialization 
 * to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded 
 * classes for that object that are compatible with respect to serialization. 
 *  Throws InvalidClassException if the object has a different serialVersionUID
 * than that of the corresponding sender's class.
 *  
 */

import java.io.*;
class Worker implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String name;
private transient int id;
private double wage;

public Worker(String name, int id, double wage){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.wage = wage;
}
public String toString(){
    return "Person with name " +
    name + " and with id " +
    id + " has a salary of " + wage + "$";
    }
}
```

Comment: `Serializable` is not a "functional interface". That term is used to describe an interface with exactly one abstract method (and is to be used as if it were just that one function). The phrase you are looking for is "marker interface". The also `Cloneable` and thankfully few others.

Comment: Agree with @TomHawtin-tackline's comment, how can an answer stating that Serializable is a Functional Interface be a valid answer.

Comment: I should also point out that although there are methods called `readObject`/`writeObject` in `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` these have a different signature to custom `readObject`/`writeObject` and are not directly related.